# How can I change PHP constants?

Tags: php, constants

I am working on making my own custom CMS in PHP by hand and I have a few constants I have defined. Is there an easy way to modify the constants?

I was thinking about using something like `fopen()` and then changing it, but I have never used the filesystem functions.

Comment: You may want to revisit the dictionary definition of "constant".

Comment: Why do you need to change your constants? If they aren't constant through out your code, use variables

Comment: Constants ARE constants - you can not modify them. If, of course, you are talking about define('constant_name', 'constant_value'); Otherwise explain on example, because it looks like you are trying to talk about changing configuration parameters of CMS in its config file, rewriting it with php script.

Comment: I know what constant's mean. I just want to know if there is a way I could change them, or something similar. I don't want to have to keep manually editing them through the php file. I am sorry that I am thinking of the wrong thing.

Comment: Maybe he's not trying to modify them during the actual run time, but he's wanting to use them as the config for his CMS and he wants his installation script to modify them or something? (Still not a good solution, just might make more sense out of the question.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> A constant is an identifier (name) for a simple value. **As the name
>   suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script**
>   (except for magic constants, which aren't actually constants). A
>   constant is case-sensitive by default. By convention, constant
>   identifiers are always uppercase.
>
> The name of a constant follows the same rules as any label in PHP. A
>   valid constant name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular
>   expression, it would be expressed thusly:
>   [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*

From: *[Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)* (PHP mamual)

Comment: cant say better than the php.net page!

Answer (score 15):

Constants are constants and therefore cannot be changed.
If you want to change the server constants such as *allow_url_fopen*, that is the host's responsibility. Ask them.

If you want to change them in PHP, use variables.

In case the truth is what Corbin says and you want to modify them in installation, you would want to do the following: 1. Change constant values to, for example, `%%constant1`. 2. read the code into a variable. 3. Let the user set the variables. 4. Use str_replace on all of them like *str_replace("%%constant1", $_POST["value1"], $configfile)*. 5. Add *$configfile* as the content of a file.

For your own CMS only, I suggest the following: store *all* constants in one file, so you will need to edit one file only. And perhaps then the previous solution could work for an easier editing, but I don't know if it is worth the time.

Answer (score 14):

No. They're **constants**, as in "[constant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/constant) - that which is permanent or invariable" (Wiktionary). Once they're defined, there is no way to change them. To quote [The Fine Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), section Constants:

> [a constant's] value cannot change during the execution of the script.

Comment: I am sorry for being incorrect... to me constants are just a value that can be used throughout an entire site without having to keep defining them. I should have been more clear what I was trying to achieve. I am creating my own CMS for my own use only and I was wondering how I could go about creating a way to change variables or whatever a good term for them would be without manually editing the file/files that contain them. I am sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize for being incorrect, it happens to everyone :)

Comment: Ok. What would the best way to create a config file be? I am going to add an admin panel to my CMS and I want the variables to be editable from there.

Answer (score 6):

No. You can not modify constants.

Comment: That statement needs to be qualified. During runtime? What about eval()?

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP means in the case of an installer script, where the OP wants to store an input variable to a configuration file, to be used in the OP's CMS, once the install is complete.

In that case the OP is not changing the constant at runtime.

The OP probably got a file like this:

```
define(DB, '');
define(USER, '');
define(PASS, '');
define(HOST, '');
```

And the OP wants to create a script that populates these constants with data, so it can be used in the CMS.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, but only if you have the runkit extension installed.

However, I must question why you're even defining a constant if you need to change it. It would no longer be a constant once changed and it's appropriate to use constants in your context if it needs to be changed. You may want to consider making it a global variable if it needs to be accessible in other functions or parts of your code, or write proper code by:

Passing the data as parameters to a function, then returning the manipulated values (if coding in a procedural fashion).

Set the value in a class' property, and then access the value using $this within your class (if coding in an object-oriented (OO) fashion).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, once set, a constant cannot be changed.

Comment: That statement needs to be qualified. During runtime? What about eval()?

Answer (score 0):

A constant mean the value is constant, so you cannot change a constant. If you will change a constant you need to use a variable instead of a constant:

```
define('ROOT', '/some/path');
echo ROOT; // Echoes /some/path
define('ROOT', '/some/other/path'); // Gives an error
echo ROOT; // Gives /some/path (if there were no error

$root = '/some/path';
echo $root; // Echoes /some/path
$root = '/some/other/path';
echo $root; // Echoes /some/other/path
```