# How to change yii constants dyanamically?

Tags: php, yii

I have defined some constants in yii components.

**component/Interst.php**

```
class Interst {
    Const Rate = 15.6%
    Const Service_tax_rate = 14.5%
}
```

I am using this in my controllers like `Interest::Service_tax_rate`. I want to change this rate on `31st May 2016` to `15.0%` this should be active from `12 AM` (at night) of `31st`. How can I code so that this would change automatically after `31st` night?

I have tried this in **Interest.php**

```
if(date('d/m/Y H:i:s') == '31/05/2016 00:00:00'){
    Const Service_tax_rate = 15%;
}
```

but this doesn't work as a condition - it's causing an error

Comment: Not sure if that's the core of the problem, I don't think `24:00:00` is going to work. Try `00:00:00` (on 1st) instead. Also the date() format looks weird

Comment: `Change` - ok. `constants` - ok. `Change constants` - what? Don't use constants if you want to change it - use variables/fields

Comment: @vp_arth Jup, that's pretty weird too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change PHP constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055991/how-to-change-php-constants)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
if(time() >= strtotime('01/06/2016 00:00:00'))
```

Make sure you have all timestamps involved in the right format (e.g. timezone)
See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
and: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

And don't define `Service_tax_rate` as `Const` (if you want to change it)